# Diesel doesnt run migrations: relation does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker, rust, docker-compose, rust-diesel

Im develop my first project with rust+diesel and I have a problem: diesel doesnt run migrations, caused by error "relation does not exist", although relations exist.
My code:
*main.rs*:

```
pub fn establish_connection() -> PgConnection {
    dotenv().ok();

    let database_url = env::var("DATABASE_URL").expect("DATABASE_URL must be set");
    PgConnection::establish(&database_url)
        .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Error connecting to {}", database_url))
}

embed_migrations!("./migrations");

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let connect = database::establish_connection();
    match embedded_migrations::run_with_output(&connect, &mut std::io::stdout()) {
        Ok(()) => println!("migrations success"),
        Err(e) => panic!("migrations error: {}", e)
    }
}
```

*Dockerfile*:

```
FROM rust:1.61 as builder
WORKDIR /build/
COPY ./Cargo.toml .
COPY ./Cargo.lock .
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./migrations ./migrations
RUN cargo build --release

FROM ubuntu:22.04 AS run
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /run/
COPY --from=builder /build/target/release/to_do .
COPY ./dist ./dist
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh .
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev
# docker-entrypoint.sh - wait 5432 port aviable & run to_do app
CMD ["sh", "docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

*docker-compose.yml*:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  postgres_db:
    image: postgres:14.3
    container_name: to_do_postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_DB_PORT}:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD}
  app:
    image: to_do_build
    container_name: to_do_app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:8080
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db
    environment: 
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://${POSTGRES_DB_USER}:${POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD}@postgres_db:${POSTGRES_DB_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB_NAME}
      - JWT_SECRET=${JWT_SECRET}
```

When im run a service by command:
`docker-compose --env-file .conf up -d`
*.conf*:

```
POSTGRES_DB_USER=to_do_user
POSTGRES_DB_NAME=to_do
POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD=to_do_password
POSTGRES_DB_PORT=5432
JWT_SECRET=secret
APP_PORT=8080
```

Service runned, but when looking at the logs:
`docker logs to_do_app`
I get an error:

```
// DATABASE_URL = postgres://to_do_user:to_do_password@postgres_db:5432/to_do
Running migration 20220525065207
Executing migration script 20220525065207/up.sql
thread 'main' panicked at 'migrations error: Failed with: relation "to_do" does not exist', src/main.rs:28:19
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Although if we connect to postgres via psql, we see that diesel has created its own system table:

```
docker exec -it to_do_postgres sh
$ psql -U to_do_user to_do
psql (14.3 (Debian 14.3-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.

to_do=# \dt
                    List of relations
 Schema |            Name            | Type  |   Owner    
--------+----------------------------+-------+------------
 public | __diesel_schema_migrations | table | to_do_user
(1 row)
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: looks like some issue with sql statement. Could you please post contents of  `20220525065207/up.sql`

Comment: *./migrations/2022-05-25-065207_create_users/up.sql*: 
`CREATE TABLE users (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, username VARCHAR NOT NULL, email VARCHAR NOT NULL, password VARCHAR NOT NULL, unique_id VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    UNIQUE (email), UNIQUE (username));
INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, unique_id) VALUES ('placeholder', 'placeholder email', 'placeholder password', 'placeholder unique id');
ALTER TABLE to_do ADD user_id integer default 1 CONSTRAINT user_id REFERENCES users NOT NULL;`

Comment: My assumption here is there are no other migration files in your project. You are altering table `to_do` which is not present in your database , that's why you are getting this `thread 'main' panicked at 'migrations error: Failed with: relation "to_do" does not exist'`.

Answer (score -1):

I was just fighting with this myself and am also using actix-web like you. It finally worked for me though after I realized that I did not have COPY ./migrations ./migrations in my Dockerfile.

Looking at yours, I see you're not copying over diesel.toml:
COPY ./diesel.toml ./diesel.toml

Would that be it?

Comment: Im tried to copy src, diesel.toml in builder and run containers - no results. I dont need to copy ./migrations folder to the run container since my migrations are embedded in the binary (crate diesel_migrations::embed_migrations!()).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).